# Casting random color in a Color array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, colors, casting

As part of a program, I need to store a random color inside of an array of colors. Basically, I created a method that should return a new random color, which I have tested, and it works. The problem that I am having is how to call that inside of another class and method. I have tried many things, and none of them work. I am pasting the relevant code below, with the instantiation for the color array at the top.

```
static Color[] colors = new Color [10000];

public static Color randomColor() {
    return new Color(generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256));
}


private class DotsListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(event))
                {
                    pointList.add(event.getPoint());
                    sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;
                    colors[pointList.size()]= new Color(event.randomColor());
```

Comment: Pass it as an argument? Not sure what exactly is your question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the method directly; you don't need to create a second new color.

```
colors[pointList.size()] = randomColor();
```

If your *randomColor()* method is in a different class, put the class name before the method call.  For example, if you have a ColorUtil class, you'd call it like this:

```
colors[pointList.size()] = ColorUtil.randomColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

What class is randomColor() in? Since it's a static method, you'd simply have to call `ClassName.randomColor();`